# Logging box in observatory is empty, how can I get logging?

Tags: dart

When I add the following code to my dart programme I expect to have some logging in observatory but instead it is empty.

```
void setupLogging() {
  Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
  Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord rec) {
     print('${rec.level.name}: ${rec.time}: ${rec.message}');
  });
}
```

And then in some method:

```
log.fine('Databases are up and running');
```

[image: observatory logging empty]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using `print` doesn't work, but the [`dart:developer`](https://api.dartlang.org/1.13.2/dart-developer/dart-developer-library.html) library contains a [`log`](https://api.dartlang.org/1.13.2/dart-developer/log.html) function that you can use for that purpose.

It has the same arguments as used by the [`LogRecord`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/logging/0.11.2/logging/LogRecord-class.html) from the [`logging`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/logging/0.11.2/) package:

```
void log(String message,
                  {DateTime time,
                   int sequenceNumber,
                   int level: 0,
                   String name: '',
                   Zone zone,
                   Object error,
                   StackTrace stackTrace});
```